# Dynamic Routing NextJS with optional paths

Tags: next.js, url-routing, dynamic-routing

Here is the issue I am trying to solve with creating dynamic routes in NextJS.

-products
   -[category]
       -[size]
          -[product]

The issue is some products don't have a size parameter and would need to bypass this parameter to get to the product landing page. Here is an example of the different routes I would like to have:

/products/ceiling-lighting/**2x4**/light-one
/products/ceiling-lighting/**2x4**/light-two
/products/ceiling-lighting/**2x2**/light-one
/products/ceiling-lighting/**2x2**/light-two
/products/light-switch/switch-one
/products/light-switch/switch-two

Is this possible to do with dynamic routes?

Comment: Im not sure if that is possible, the last two links will point to [size]/index.js and not [size]/[product].js

Comment: You could potentially make it work using a [catch-all route](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes#catch-all-routes).

Answer (score 0):

Nope it will not work, you have to pass required number to parameters/segments to reach that specific dynamic page, but as juliomalves said, you can use [catch all routes](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes#catch-all-routes), after using this you will get your parameters in the form of array and you can navigate programmatically depending on number of parameters or whatever logic you want.